# Oracle Apex: JQUERY droppable not recognized

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In the below code written in Oracle Apex 5, draggable works but droppable is not recognized.

```
$('.draggable').draggable({ revert: "invalid"});

$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        $(this).text() = draggable.text();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle APEX only loads the components of jQuery UI that are required for base APEX functionality. Entire jQuery UI library is not included by APEX as it would significantly impact page performance. Droppable component is not included in APEX by default. You can activate Droppable component of jQuery UI by including following file in *Page -> Javascript -> File URLs* property

```
#IMAGE_PREFIX#libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.22/ui/minified/jquery.ui.droppable.min.js
```

Try below code, to check whether APEX recognized jQuery UI Droppable component

```
$('.draggable').draggable({ revert: "invalid"});

$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("dropped");
    }
});
```

For more information on this, check out Oracle Docs --> [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/app_comp001.htm#BABJDCEE)